# Why cannot I reference the second alias from a subquery containing a UNION?

Tags: mysql, query, subquery, union, alias

Why cannot I use `Qty2` as an alias in my query? I receive this error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'qty2' in 'field list'

```
SELECT mat, qty, qty2, SUM(qty), (ifnull(SUM(qty - qty2),0)) as TotalQty
 FROM (
   SELECT 11_counted_stock.part_number as mat, 
          SUM(11_counted_stock.quantity) AS qty
    FROM 11_counted_stock
    GROUP BY 11_counted_stock.part_number
 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11_stock_actual_whs_costed.material as mat, 
         SUM(11_stock_actual_whs_costed.available_stock) AS qty2
    FROM 11_stock_actual_whs_costed
    GROUP BY 11_stock_actual_whs_costed.material
)t
WHERE mat = '4532028959'
GROUP BY mat
```

Answer (score 4):

Column names in the `UNION` query are assigned based on the first `SELECT`, and you can't have different names for the same (second) column in the result.

My guess would be you want a `JOIN`, not a `UNION`.